# what range of orbital inclinations will be needed to reach Mars from the Boca Chica launch site?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, orbital-elements

When SpaceX fly missions out of Boca Chica in South Texas to Mars what orbital inclination will the launch need to be to put the spacecraft on to best transfer orbit to Mars? And will this vary with the time of year and the launch opportunity? If so by how much?

Comment: biggest variability is in time of day of launch